# How to convert .mat data file to yaml file?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I am really new to Matlab and have .mat files for a 3D model. I need to convert it into yaml file for use in opencv. I need to create it in a similar format as this repo has done: https://github.com/shaoguangcheng/faceFrontalization/tree/master/3DModel

I have checked into a lot of questions and seen people post matlabtoopencv codes. I have tried to run them but they return errors. I am extremely new to matlab and cant edit the code (just got to know that matlab uses .m for code files). So I need an easy way to convert .mat file to similar structure as given in repo.

The location for actual .mat files: 
`http://www.openu.ac.il/home/hassner/projects/frontalize/`
go to the ftp server and download `frontalization.0.1.3.zip`. It has required .mat files.

Please help. Need to complete my project.

PS: I tried following this question: [Converting a .mat file from MATLAB into cv::Mat matrix in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550021/converting-a-mat-file-from-matlab-into-cvmat-matrix-in-opencv#comment15305337_11561508)

It gives this error on calling csvwrite()
error:

```
??? Input argument "m" is undefined.

Error in ==> csvwrite at 32
dlmwrite(filename, m, ',', r, c);
```

Comment: frontalization is gone

Comment: the frontalization code is no longer at that ftp site.  i guess the author removed it?

Comment: The code is still there. Try going to the repo itself by this link: https://github.com/shaoguangcheng/faceFrontalization